# How do I install the pip package for python on mac osx?

Tags: python, macos, pip, virtualenv, nose

I'm currently stuck on exercise 46 in Zed Shaw's "Learn Python the Hardway". He says I need to install the following python packages:

1. [pip](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip)
2. [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute)
3. [nose](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose)
4. [virtualenv](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

He doesn't give the reader any directions on how to properly install the packages and use them. I went to the pip website but the directions were also very vague and kind of unhelpful for a newbie. The installation guide found on https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html says to download the `get-pip.py` file and then run it by typing `python get-pip.py` in what I presume to be terminal.

When I do that it starts downloading, then says `cleaning up..` and then a red error message appears that says:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):" 

followed by a bunch of file names before ending with 

"OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip
```

Does anyone know how to correct this? If it helps, the `get-pip.py` file is in my downloads folder, so I did `cd Downloads` before running `python get-pip.py"`

Comment: You could run it with `sudo`, as in `sudo python get-pip.py`. Alternatively, you could look into installing python and pip via homebrew: http://brew.sh

Comment: I installed homebrew but when I ran the 'brew doctor' command in terminal it gave me a warning saying: "You have leftover files from an older version of Xcode.
You should delete them using:
  /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder" I ran the command it suggested but all it did was say "Can't determine system version". Also when I tried manually looking up the uninstall-dev folders and running them nothing happened. Any suggestions?

Comment: nvm. Figured it out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

or install it with homebrew: http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/

and then:

```
brew install python
```

Answer (score 1):

The error-message is IMHO pretty clear - you are not allowed to write into the given directory.

The reason for this is that you use the system-provided Python 2.7. While installing pip shouldn't break it, I personally would rather download a Python 2.7 installer, install it, and then do

```
$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python get-pip.py
```

This should install pip into this python, and place the pip-executable at the same location as just given

```
$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
```

If you insist on using the system python, make it "sudo python get-pip.py". But I wouldn't mess with my system python unless forced to.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install `pip` is:

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```