# Homebrew: Need help deleting leftover files from an older version(s) of xcode

Tags: python, xcode, homebrew, uninstallation

I decided to get pip and other python packages via homebrew after receiving answers to a question I asked earlier: [How do I install the pip package for python on mac osx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24191799/how-do-i-install-the-pip-package-for-python-on-mac-osx)

So I installed homebrew, and then ran the 'brew doctor' command in terminal after it finished. When I did this, I got a warning saying:

"Warning: You have leftover files from an older version of Xcode.
You should delete them using:
  /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder"

I ran the suggested command "/Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder" but all I got in return was "Can't determine system version"

I tried manually looking up the uninstall-dev files, but when I ran one it gave me an error message saying it

"must be run with root permissions -- prefix command with 'sudo'"

I did some research and some sites were suggesting to run the command:

"sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all"

but it seemed like that would delete all versions of xcode, including the 5.1 version that I want to keep. Is there anyway to safely delete the older versions of xcode on my computer without corrupting the current version or any other files? I'm a little reluctant to use sudo without knowing for sure what will happen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apple states you can just delete the developer folder that previous versions used for tools / frameworks. I did this a bit ago and it was fine.

I confirmed this on apple's website too:

"Previous versions of Xcode placed the tools and frameworks in the Developer folder. You can delete the older version of Xcode by dragging the Developer folder to the trash."

See https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/